# getifaddrs for en1 gives 3 different addresses

Tags: networking

After using getifaddrs and I am looking at en1 wireless interfaces. When I printed them out I have seen 3 different interfaces for en1.

```
en1              Unknown family (18)

en1              fe80::219:e3ff:fe04:ac2d

en1              10.185.199.30
```

I think only the last one has a valid IP address. Why the other two existed?

Answer (score 1):

> I think only the last one has a valid IP address.

Yes, it's a valid IPv4 address.

> Why the other two existed?

The interface has more than one address.

`fe80::219:e3ff:fe04:ac2d` is an IPv6 address.

I assume the `18` in `Unknown family (18)` refers to an address family number, in which case, [`18` is `AS Number`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/address-family-numbers/address-family-numbers.xhtml).

Comment: I know, old question, but bears pointing out that the link cited is not the correct link for `AF_*` constants (nor is there one), and that `18` is not "AS Number." `AF_*` constants are OS-dependent and they are not always the same. `AF_INET` (IPv4) is `2` on Linux, BSD, and macOS, but `AF_INET6` (IPv6) is `10` on Linux, `24` on openBSD, and `30` on macOS. Meanwhile, `18` is `AF_LINK` (the MAC address) on openBSD and macOS. Linux does not have `AF_LINK` but instead has `AF_PACKET` = `17`, also the MAC address. `18` on Linux is `AF_ASH`, so OP is probably macOS. https://godbolt.org/z/zWaTfzq3h